# QGIS using the heatmapplugin from the console

Tags: qgis, python, heat-map

I have to make a lot of heatmaps from csv's. Therefore I'm making a python script to run in the console.

So far I can load csv's and save them as shapefiles. To get to the heatmapplugin I'm using the following code:

```
rasterMenu = qgis.utils.iface.rasterMenu()
for rasterMenuItem in rasterMenu.actions():
    if 'Heatmap' in rasterMenuItem.text():
    heatmapMenu = rasterMenuItem

    for heatmapMenuItem in heatmapMenu.menu().actions():
        print heatmapMenuItem
        if 'Heatmap' in heatmapMenuItem.text():
            heatmapMenuItem.trigger()
```

Now I'm stuck. Does somebody know how to select the heatmap menu and enter the correct variables from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

Instead of the heatmapplugin I used the kernel density estimation algorithm:

```
import processing
processing.runandload("saga:kerneldensityestimation", "path/to/shapefile.shp", "name of the colums with weigths", radius, 0, 0, None, celsize, "path/to/raster.tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
processing.runAndLoad("qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation", {'INPUT':'[Path to input 
layer]','RADIUS':[value],'RADIUS_FIELD':None,'PIXEL_SIZE': 
[value],'WEIGHT_FIELD':None,'KERNEL':0,'DECAY':0,'OUTPUT_VALUE':0,'OUTPUT':'[path to 
 output].tiff'})
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. Could you explain your answer? Answers are encouraged to have a small explanation instead of being one-liners.