# Heatmap Processing Exception in QGIS 3.2

Tags: heat-map, qgis-3

I am working through training exercises with the Alaska training data using QGIS 3.2 on Windows 8.  To create a Heatmap, I load the airports shapefile.

I cannot find the Heatmap plugin using the Plugins Manager for QGIS 3.2 so I try using Processing Tools/Interpolation/Heatmap(KDE) and set the radius to 300000.  I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Heatmap.py", line 215, in processAlgorithm
self.tr('Could not create destination layer'))
_core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create destination layer

Execution failed after 0.09 seconds

I am assuming the Interpolation/Heatmap(KDE) is not the correct tool to use.  Is there a way to get the Heatmap plugin?

Comment: try this  using the console, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121683/qgis-using-the-heatmapplugin-from-the-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new version of QGIS:

1. Right click on your layer.
2. Select Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog, switch to the Style tab.
4. Select Heatmap as the renderer and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, but I invoked my copy of qgis from the console and noticed the following error message.

> ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 296422699008 bytes, whereas 3806478785935080 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
>   Critical: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Heatmap.py", line 214, in processAlgorithm
>       self.tr('Could not create destination layer'))
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create destination layer

Why it needs this much disk space is a bit of a mystery!

But adding a envronment called CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE set to false made the tool work until it ran out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I want to throw my hat into the ring here.

The size of the radius and the pixel can affect how many columns the final raster will generate. Large radii and small pixel sizes will generate an astronomical amount of columns and will return the error message, which, as @Dave pointed out, is due to the amount of space that the final raster will generate.

If your radius is set to 300000, consider increasing the sizes of the pixel as well. Try to get the number of columns to < 2000. If the radius is that large, I'd imagine that the scale you're trying to create a heatmap for is quite large as well (global? regional?), so I'd suspect very large pixels wouldn't reduce the quality of what you're producing.